# Escaping ' and & and similar characters in url

Tags: javascript, url, urlencode, url-encoding

I need a way to encode both `'` and `&` in a url. Check the following examples:

```
// "get_records.php?artist=Mumford%20%26%20Sons"
"get_records.php?artist=" + encodeURIComponent("Mumford & Sons"); 

// "get_records.php?artist=Gigi%20D'Agostinos"
"get_records.php?artist=" + encodeURIComponent("Gigi D'Agostino");
```

`encodeURIComponent` doesn't encode `'`. I can use `escape` instead, but it's deprecated, I guess. What do I do in this case? Create a custom encoder?

---

I'll be escaping other characters too: `:`, `/`, `.`, `,`, `!`, for example, for the following strings

```
"11:59"
"200 km/h in the Wrong Lane"
"P.O.D."
"Everybody Else Is Doing It, So Why Can't We"
"Up!"
```

So creating a custom encoder seems like the best option. Is there an alternative approach that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement this functionality yourself.

MDN covers this exact topic. Extending their proposal to cover the `&` character and others as well should be trival.

> To be more stringent in adhering to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (which reserves !, ', (, ), and *), even though these characters have no formalized URI delimiting uses, the following can be safely used:
>
> ```
> function fixedEncodeURIComponent (str) {
>   return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
>     return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
>   });
> }
> ```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace characters before create URL.

```
' = %27
```

Check this: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp